# Match USB serial # to port name with Qt and libusb

Tags: c++, qt, usbserial

I have a device that acts as a serial port connected over USB. I have a class that interfaces with the device through a `QSerialPort`. Soon I will have multiple such devices and the program will need to reliably distinguish them to assign configured values to instances of the class.

Qt identifies serial devices by the `portName` field of the `QSerialPortInfo` helper object. This name is derived from the /dev/ path (e.g. `/dev/tty.foo42` is port name `"foo42"`) and this path does not remain associated with a particular device over reboots or deployment to a different machine. However, through libusb I can get a serial number, which is stable across reboots and different machines.

What I am still missing is a way to match the serial number, which can be identified in advance and recorded in a configuration file, to a port name, which can be used to open a `QSerialPort`. Currently deploying to MacOS, but in the future we may wish to deploy to Linux.

Searching existing questions mostly turns up ways to configure a Linux system to always assign a particular dev path to a particular device. A solution that involves configuring the operating system is acceptable, but something the application can do without that is preferable. A Mac specific solution is acceptable, but something that also works on Linux is preferable.

Comment: Do you familiar with `/udev/rules` (I'm not sure that it's what you need)?

Comment: @Gluttton I saw that path name during the searching I did before asking this question, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Have you tried QSerialPortInfo::serialNumber()?

Comment: @MrEricSir Introduced in Qt5.3. I've been working in 5.2. I'll comment again after I try it.

Comment: @MrEricSir Yeah, that does exactly what I need. Post as an answer and collect your bounty.

Comment: @01d55 Great to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [QSerialPortInfo::serialNumber()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qserialportinfo.html#serialNumber) (new in Qt 5.3) sounds like what you're after:

> QString QSerialPortInfo::serialNumber() const
>
> Returns the serial number string of the serial port, if available;
>   otherwise returns an empty string.
>
> Note: The serial number may include letters.